# Show entries by author

Tags: channel-entries, entries, author

is there a simple out of the box approach to showing entries created by their author?
EG: after an article I want to list a credit like so:

**"article by AUTHOR"**

and allow a *click through* from the *AUTHOR link* to a template featuring just that author's entries…

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can include the author's name and a link using the [`author`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#author) and [`author_id`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#id4) variables. For example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    {body}
    <p>Posted by <a href="/blog/author/{author_id}">{author}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then, at its most basic, create a template to display posts filtered by author (the template used in the example above is `blog.group/author.html`). In that template, filter the Channel entries with the [`author_id`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#author-id) parameter.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" author_id="{segment_3}"}
    {if count == "1"}
        <h1>All Posts by {author}</h1>
        <ul>
    {/if}

    <li>{title}</li>

    {if count == total_results}
        </ul>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to use a possible 'Zoo Visitor' or 'Playa' approach for just this functionality. This is great.

Comment: You're welcome! On Stack Exchange you can accept an answer by ticking the checkmark on the left. This is optional, but generally encouraged if an answer provided you with a solution. See http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

BTW at least with EE2 it's important to include the parameter dynamic="off" to make this work. Example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="features" author_id="{segment_3}" dynamic="off" }
```